# Why can't I unlock the Bureau of Bureaucracy?

Tags: simcity-4

I believe my current city meets all the requirements to build the Bureau of Bureaucracy, yet I am unable to unlock it.

Many websites state its requirements to be the following:

- Residential population: 39,000
- Mayor rating: 30
- Education funding: 101%
- Health funding: 101%
- Courthouse has been built

My city is as follows:

- Residential population: 185,000
- Mayor rating: 100
- Education funding: Every individual building funded *at least* 110%
- Health funding: Every individual building funded *at least* 110%
- Courthouse has been built (more than 100 years ago)

So why is the button still grayed out? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This page](http://www.simphoni.net/forums/index.php?s=d32755ad6e2cc0221dc1aedfa20eceba&showtopic=13683&view=findpost&p=333131) gives three alternatives, I'll expand on them where necessary:

1. Fund all education and health buildings to their maximums for several months.
   Make sure none of those building are currently used over their maximum capacity and that you have enough money in reserve to pay for this before you attempt it.
2. Unlock the building through a U-Drive-it mission. (Requires Rush Hour or Deluxe.)
   The associated mission is "Mayor's Got New Socks!", a news van mission. You need a television studio and a mayor's house to be able to play this mission.
3. Cheat. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to open the cheat box and type "`you don't deserve it`"
   This will unlock all buildings. There's no way to undo this.

**Option 1** worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 'reward' for bad city management. "The Bureau of Bureaucracy is a Civic Trophy Reward Building that serves as an icon of bad City Services management."    https://www.wiki.sc4devotion.com/index.php?title=Bureau_of_Bureaucracy